# Huge delay in script response when using SFTP with expect

Tags: shell-script, ftp, sftp, expect, timeout

I am using a script to call SFTP service to fetch some logs from the remote server. This works fine in normal scenario but, i have noticed a very long delay of around 30 minutes or more in some of the cases when the server expects the password. Following is the code i am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirdate=`/bin/date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`

INPUT_DIR="/root/SDP_BHC/input"
CREDENTIALS_FILE="/root/FTP_TEST/Credentials.csv"

# Loop to read credentials and other details from an external file.
while IFS=','; read node_id node_name ip1 ip2 ip3 user1 pass1 user2 pass2 user3 pass3 installed location circle sdpno hwtype
do

        # Generate Input Directory for IP-Node
        mkdir -p $INPUT_DIR/"$node_id"/"$node_name"/IP/"$dirdate"

        echo -e "\n[INFO] Node IP: $ip1"
        echo -e "=============================\n"

        SOURCE_FILE="/var/opt/fds/statistics/*PSC-TrafficHandler_8*1_A_*_System*$dirdate*stat"
        TARGET_DIR="$INPUT_DIR/$node_id/$node_name/IP/$dirdate"


set prompt "(%|#|\\$|%\]) $"
spawn /usr/bin/sftp $user1@$ip1
expect { "$prompt" }
#expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
#bin prompt
send "yes\r"
#expect "Password:"
expect { "$prompt" }
send "$pass1\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
set timeout 2000
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD

.
.
.

done < $CREDENTIALS_FILE
```

The script hangs in some cases like when the password updated in the `CREDENTIALS_FILE` is not matching (because of password change in the source server from where file is being fetched). In such case, the password entry gets two responses (yes and $pass1) and then hangs for third password prompt since first two are wrong. Here, it hangs for a very long time (in some cases it doesn't which is another confusion i have why it doesn't happen in those cases).

Anyways, whatever the case maybe i want to make the SFTP session timeout quickly if any of such scenario happens. How do i make the session to get a timeout quickly if the passwords do not match at all? I am already using a `timeout`. For a normal session, my script takes a max of 30-35 seconds to connect to the servers and FTP the files to the local machine.

Could anyone please provide some pointers regarding how to fix this issue?

Comment: Want to update one point here, the SFTP operations are completed withing 30-35 seconds for a single server (same for all other servers whose details are updated in the credentials file) to copy the files to the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to the sftp command the option

```
-o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1
```

to stop it asking twice for passwords. You might usefully also try

```
-o ConnectTimeout=20
-o ConnectionAttempts=1
```

Comment: Thanks, What is 20 here? 20 seconds? If i give -o ConnectTimeout=20, will it disconnect the session even if some transfer is going on?

Comment: yes, it is 20 seconds. It just applies to trying to connect. Once transfer starts it is not used.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the ConnectTimeout=20 somehow didn't work for me, i waited and the connection never got timed out even after couple of minutes. However, i tried the second option -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=2 which worked like a charm and solved my issue. Could you suggest why the Timeout didn't work? I mean something keeps holding the timeout option back from getting used during connection.

Comment: I can only suppose that it does connect enough to decide the timeout is no longer useful, and then hangs a bit later in the connection process. You might get further clues by adding `-v` to `sftp` to get some debug output, provided it doesnt interfere with your expect script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this modified script. You have to use `set timeout 2000` before `mget`.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirdate=`/bin/date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`

INPUT_DIR="/root/SDP_BHC/input"
CREDENTIALS_FILE="/root/FTP_TEST/Credentials.csv"

# Loop to read credentials and other details from an external file.
while IFS=','; read node_id node_name ip1 ip2 ip3 user1 pass1 user2 pass2 user3 pass3 installed location circle sdpno hwtype
do

        # Generate Input Directory for IP-Node
        mkdir -p $INPUT_DIR/"$node_id"/"$node_name"/IP/"$dirdate"

        echo -e "\n[INFO] Node IP: $ip1"
        echo -e "=============================\n"

        SOURCE_FILE="/var/opt/fds/statistics/*PSC-TrafficHandler_8*1_A_*_System*$dirdate*stat"
        TARGET_DIR="$INPUT_DIR/$node_id/$node_name/IP/$dirdate"


set prompt "(%|#|\\$|%\]) $"
spawn /usr/bin/sftp $user1@$ip1
expect { "$prompt" }
#expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
#bin prompt
send "yes\r"
#expect "Password:"
expect { "$prompt" }
send "$pass1\r"
expect "sftp>"
set timeout 2000;
send "mget $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD

.
.
.

done < $CREDENTIALS_FILE
```